# Hide \makeemptybox or \fillwithdottedlines in solution

Tags: exam

In a `exam` document I would like the solution to take place of the \fillwithdottedlines{3cm} field I have.

For example, I have this:

```
\question Effectuez les additions...
\begin{parts}
\part $1 + 51$
\makeemptybox{3cm}
\begin{solution}
\begin{lstlisting}
        11
  00000001 = 0x01 = 1
+ 00110011 = 0x33 = 51
----------
00110100 = 0x34 = 52
\end{lstlisting}
\end{solution}
\end{parts}
```

It gives this:

[image]

What is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ifprintanswers`, as in

```
\ifprintanswers
Stuff to appear only when answers are being printed.
\else
Stuff to appear only when answers are not being printed.
\fi
```

You can choose not to put anything in between the `\ifprintanswers` and the `\else`.